# confused about grammar in question sentences

Tags: grammar, questions

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

1. Did you know that he has cheated on you?
2. Do you know that he always has been telling you to stop making a joke?

I guess I am quite a bit confused when it comes to do/did question sentences, whether I can follow it up with present perfect/past perfect tense.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical, although the second is a little awkward. It isn't clear what concerns you here. Were you taught that a _Do_ question can't be followed by a use of the perfect?

Comment: it has been a while since I decided to learn english again, I don't think I have been taught about that I am just making sure cause my memory is a little bit hazy.

My next question is that why do you think the second question was kinda awkward?

also, can I use past tense / past perfect tense after "Do you know" ?

Comment: A native speaker would never use the construction _"Did you know that he always has been…"_ We would not place the adverb between the subject and verb of such a clause. We would say not _"Did you know that he **always has been** telling..."_ but rather _"Did you know that he **kept** telling..."_

Comment: Yes, you may use any time perspective you prefer after _"Do you know."_ For example, **_"Do you know that the warp drive was to have been disabled sfter 12.6 quintillion parsecs of duty?"_**

Comment: @P. E.  Dant The present perfect simple expresses an action that is
still going on or that stopped recently, but has an influence on the present.  How can it fit with "past simple "?  Isn't it two different time frame? I think  "Did you know that he has cheated on you? " can only fit if he has continued cheating upto present .  Can you explain please?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. _"Did/do you know that he has cheated on you?"_ tells us only that he cheated in the past. It tells us nothing about whether the cheating is still going on in the present. He might have cheated once, ten years ago, and never since. If you want to express that the cheating is still going on, you have to say so, e.g.; _"Did/do you know that he **keeps cheating** on you?"_ ..or ..  _"Did/do you know that he **is still cheating** on you?"_ (There is no difference here between _"Did you know..."_ and _"Do you know..."_ We use both forms idiomatically.)

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences are correct and understandable.

Your second sentence

> Do you know that he **always has been** telling you to stop making a joke?

might be reworded as

> Do you know that he **has always been** telling you to stop making a joke?

and the phrase

> to stop making a joke

sounds incomplete, it could be

> to stop making a joke **about** *(something)*

or you might mean

> to stop joking around

which is an idiom.